# Confusion regarding super use in Generics Java

Tags: java, generics

I want to define relationship between two type parameters in Java and I know using wildcard would be a better option,still wanted to use two type parameters with super relationship.But i am not able to do so.
Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong(It gives compiler error "super"expected)

```
 public static <T,S super T> T writeAll(Collection<T> coll, Class<S> snk) {

            return null;

        }

      public static <T,S> T writeAllTwo(Collection<T> coll, Class<S super T> snk) {

            return null;

        }
```

Comment: You could use `<S, T extends S>`

Comment: Yes,i know about extends but are we allowed to use a type for super instead of wildcard?If yes how and if no why not..